# Color multiple words inside a textjoin formula

Tags: excel, vba, colors, textjoin, instr

I have cells with a concatenated list of words (with textjoin) and I want to colorate words differently to make it more readable.
Just an example to better explain my problem:
5 Apples / 2 Oranges / 3 Bananas / 5 Apples / 2 Kiwis / 3 Oranges
I would need to put the apples in red and the oranges in orange.

Do you have a solution on this?
Thanks in advance!

I was able to find an example on this forum to color text in cells using VBA and the InStr function, but the problem I am having is that the words are often repeated and InStr doesn't work for multiple entries:

```
AppleStartPosition = InStr(1, CurrentCellText, "Apple")
If AppleStartPosition > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Col).Characters(AppleStartPosition, 5).Font.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

Comment: Your code will have to convert the cells from formulas to static values first. `Instr` will work for multiple entries - you just have to loop adjusting the start position (first argument)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I tackled this issue using regex. I've been looping a dictionary as an example, making sure in the pattern that we are being explicit about the value we are looking for using boundaries! This way I tried to minimize the possibility of false positives being colored. For example 'Apple' in 'Apple Pie'.

---

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim re As Object: Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim cl As Range: Set cl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

'Assert we are dealing with a value instead of formula:
cl.Value = cl.Value

'Choose how you wish to run through word/color combo's. I used a dictionary:
dict.Add "Apples", 3
dict.Add "Oranges", 46

'Loop through the dictionary, adjust the regex pattern and replace font colors:
For Each Key In dict.Keys
    With re
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d\s)" & Key & "(?=\s+\/|$)"
        If .Test(cl) Then
            For Each rMatch In .Execute(cl.Value)
                cl.Characters(rMatch.FirstIndex + 3, rMatch.Length - 2).Font.ColorIndex = dict(Key)
            Next rMatch
        End If
    End With
Next Key

End Sub
```

---

If you need to color the actual numbers too then:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim re As Object: Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim cl As Range: Set cl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

'Assert we are dealing with a value instead of formula:
cl.Value = cl.Value

'Choose how you wish to run through word/color combo's. I used a dictionary:
dict.Add "Apples", 3
dict.Add "Oranges", 46

'Loop through the dictionary, adjust the regex pattern and replace font colors:
For Each Key In dict.Keys
    With re
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\d+\s" & Key & "(?=\s+\/|$)"
        If .Test(cl) Then
            For Each rMatch In .Execute(cl.Value)
                cl.Characters(rMatch.FirstIndex + 1, rMatch.Length).Font.ColorIndex = dict(Key)
            Next rMatch
        End If
    End With
Next Key

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Rory commented first convert to static value the cell content e.g. with Copy and PasteSpecial/Values either in excel or in vba and then

This is an example code where

**cellofrange** is the range to color

**colarr** is the array of the colors to apply

this colors the letters only and change a color when a non letter character found.

```
Sub colorer()
    Dim cellofrange As Range, cellof As Range
    Set cellofrange = Range("a19:a24")
    colarr = Array(rgbSeaGreen, rgbSienna, rgbSlateGrey, rgbSlateBlue, rgbSkyBlue)
    colpointer = 0
    For Each cellof In cellofrange
        changed = False
        stringtocolor = cellof.Value
        For i = 1 To Len(stringtocolor)
            charact = Mid(stringtocolor, i, 1)
            If Asc(charact) > 64 And Asc(charact) < 91 Or Asc(charact) > 96 And Asc(charact) < 123 Then
                cellof.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = colarr(colpointer)
                changed = False
            ElseIf Not changed Then
                changed = True
                If colpointer = UBound(colarr) Then
                    colpointer = 0
                Else
                    colpointer = colpointer + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next cellof
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snipped:

```
Option Explicit
'
' cell A1 contains:
' 5 Apples / 2 Oranges / 3 Bananas / 5 Apples / 2 Kiwis / 3 Oranges / 4 Raspberries
'
' The second parameter is the HighLight String a # symbol and the color in hex

Sub TEST()
    ColorCell Range("A1:A3"), "Apples#FF0000,Oranges#00FF00"
End Sub


Private Sub ColorCell(cellRange As Range, ColorOpt As String, Optional Separator = " ")
Dim aItems() As String, aColorOpt() As String, aItm() As String, ColorTab() As Variant, aCell() As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, tx As String, element As String, Item As String, co As String, mx As Long, rr As Range, po As Integer

    
    aColorOpt = Split(ColorOpt, ",")
    mx = UBound(aColorOpt)
    ReDim ColorTab(mx, 1)
    For i = 0 To mx
        aItm = Split(aColorOpt(i), "#")
        Item = aItm(0)
        co = aItm(1)
        ColorTab(i, 0) = Item
        ColorTab(i, 1) = co
    Next
            
    For Each rr In cellRange.Cells
        aItems = Split(rr.Value, Separator)
        rr.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        rr.Font.TintAndShade = 0
        po = 1
        For i = 0 To UBound(aItems)
            For j = 0 To mx
                If (InStr(Trim(LCase(aItems(i))), Trim(LCase(ColorTab(j, 0)))) > 0) Then
                    rr.Characters(po, Len(aItems(i))).Font.Color = Val("&H" & ColorTab(j, 1))
                End If
            Next
            po = po + Len(aItems(i)) + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```